# Connecting to a WNR2000v4 Netgear Router via Serial Connection with an Arduino Uno and a sketch?

Tags: arduino-uno

I was reading in the OpenWRT wiki that you can indeed connect to the serial TTY console of an Open WRT roouter using the serial console if you're careful aabout the voltages.  https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/hardware/port.serial.cables#method_b_no_physical_changes_to_arduino_board

However, I don't know anything about the voltages of my particular model of OpenWRT router a Netgear WNR2000v4.  I know that it is accessible via 3 holes on the board but I know nothing of the voltages.  Does anyone know or have experince with this about what voltages / wires to use to access it via the serial console?

Comment: 3.3V. It's always 3.3V.

Comment: You can also find this information about the voltage of 3.3V on the site you linked

Comment: Why do you want to attach an Arduino to the UART port in the first place? If you can flash LEDE / OpenWRT on it or just activate the Telnet port, you can also remote-control the router, without having to have a Arduino logging into it over serial.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Because the flashing didn't go so well...

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Will this do it? https://www.hotmcu.com/cp2102-module-usb-to-33v-ttl-p-35.html

Comment: @leeand00 I'm not sure if the CP2102 in this design outputs 5V or 3.3V on the TX pin. I'd buy a FT232RL module (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B014Y1IMNM) because there is a jumper to select either 5V or 3.3V output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The WNR2000v4 serial port is at JP1: 115200 8N1 at 3.3V. Pads are, from left to right with the ethernet ports on right: [GND] [Rx] [Tx] [Vcc]

Source: https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/netgear/wnr2000, PCB picture: https://wiki.openwrt.org/_detail/media/netgear/wnr2000/wnr2000v1_pcb_detail_small.jpg?id=toh%3Anetgear%3Awnr2000

Comment: So it has a mofset in it?

Comment: I have some wires that seem like they would work...they have little female ends on them; how am I going to know if the wires are okay for 3.3v?

Comment: If you are not connecting to a PC serial port, you do not need the mosfet. You linked Method B in your question, so I was operating under the assumption that was the path you chose forward.

It's not the wires you have to worry about at such low voltages, it's the device on the other end. If your Arduino is one with a atmega16u2, then it will work fine to hook up per your link.

Comment: @leeand00 For communication you only need to connect (from Arduino to Router) GND -> GND, RX -> TX, TX -> RX over a voltage divider. 3.3V is high enough to register as a '1' with the Arduino's 5V logic. Don't put your Arduino's 5V TX signal into the router though, use a simple voltage divider (example https://randomnerdtutorials.com/how-to-level-shift-5v-to-3-3v/)